# Positioning Background Image on Canvas Correctly Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to load a background image on canvas and position game camera on certain position and zoom level.

This is the example background image:

http://i.hizliresim.com/3zYlaA.png

When i load the image it looks like this
[image]

I want to set position of background image (or camera ? )like this:

[image]

Canvas is 800x600

```
const preload = () => {

  game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

  game.load.image("background", "http://i.hizliresim.com/3zYlaA.png")

};

const create = () => {
  cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

   background = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'background');
    //  Creates a layer from the World1 layer in the map data.
    //  A Layer is effectively like a Phaser.Sprite, so is added to the display list.


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot access the image that you linked. But I'm going to guess you want to center the picture.

If your game is simple enough and is not going to use camera in future, you can just move or enlarge the tile sprite.

```
background = game.add.tileSprite(x, y, width, height, 'background');
```